# Make a DIV display as block when content is larger than parent else display as inline-block

Tags: html, css

I want to generate a question paper on a quiz site. In this question paper an option can be a small text or large group of HTML elements. What I want is that if the content of the option DIV is larger than the remaining width of the container then it should display as block else it should display as inline-block.
Here is my code:

```css
.parent{
  width: 400px
}
.option {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.alphabet{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div><b>16. This is a sample question?</b></div>
  <div>This is sample question description.</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">a</span>. Option 1</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">b</span>. VERY LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG OPTION</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">c</span>. Option 3</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">d</span>. sdsds</div>
</div>
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: remove the width:50% ?

Comment: Flex would be usefull here ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I do that then 3 tiny options will get displayed in one row. I want only two in one row they are displayed as inline-block.

Comment: @G-Cyr tried it but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a flexbox solution:

```css
.parent{
  width: 400px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.option {
  min-width:50%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.alphabet{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div><b>16. This is a sample question?</b></div>
  <div>This is sample question description.</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">a</span>. Option 1</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">b</span>. VERY LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG OPTION</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">c</span>. Option 3</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">d</span>. sdsds</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">c</span>. Option 3</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">b</span>. VERY LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG</div>
  <div class="option"><span class="alphabet">d</span>. sdsds</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the browser compatibility for this?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva almost 100%: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox .. flexbox is now supported everywhere and I am not using any complex feature so even the small bugs in some browser won't apply here.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use JavaScript to get all the options:

`var options = document.getElementsByClassName("option");`

and then go through them with a for loop, option by option,
compare their `option.innerHTML` (content) length
to the width of the parent object.

If the content is longer than its container, you can use
`option.style["display"] = "block";`
to change the display attribute.

Comment: I need it in CSS. If JavaScript was an option I wouldn't have asked this question.